# How can I get a related Asset of a specific field?

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, assetfilemodel

I'm trying to grab an Asset which is a child of my Entry...

```php
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset);
$criteria->childOf = $entryId;
$photo = craft()->assets->findFile($criteria);
```

For the most part, this works pretty well. But my entry has multiple Asset fields, and **sometimes it grabs the wrong image**.

I suspect that I just need to add another parameter to my `$criteria`, but I can't figure out what... theoretically something to denote which specific field I'm referring to. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! The specific field can be targeted like this:

```
$criteria->childField = 'myFieldHandle';
```